# Retrieving gobs written to file by appending several times

Tags: file, go, append, gob

I am trying to use encoding/gob to store data to a file and load it later. I want to be able to append new data to the file and load all saved data later, e.g. after restarting my application. While storing to the file using Encode() there are no problems, but when reading it seems I always get only the item which was first stored, not the succinctly stored items.

Here is a minimal example: https://play.golang.org/p/patGkKDLhM

As you see, it works to write two times to an encoder and then read it back. But when closing the file and reopening it again in append mode, writing seems to work, but reading works only for the first two elements (which have been written previously). The two newly added structs cannot be retrieved, I get the error:

> panic: extra data in buffer

I am aware of [Append to golang gob in a file on disk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30927993/append-to-golang-gob-in-a-file-on-disk) and I also read https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/golang-nuts/bn6vjC5Abd8

Finally, I also found https://gist.github.com/kjk/8015952 which seems to demonstrate that what I am trying to do does not work. Why? What does this error mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have not used the `encoding/gob` package yet (looks cool, I might have to find a project for it).  But reading the godoc, it would seem to me that each encoding is a single record expected to be decoded from beginning to end.  That is, once you `Encode` a stream, the resulting bytes is a complete set respecting the entire stream from start to finish - not able to be appended to later by encoding again.

The godoc states that an encoded `gob` is self-descriptive.  At the beginning of the encoded stream, it describes the entire data set struct, types, etc that will be following including the field names.  Then what follows in the byte stream is the the size and byte representation of the value of those Exported fields.

Then one could assume that what is omitted from the docs is since the stream self-describes itself at the very beginning, *including each field that is about to be passed*, that is all that the `Decoder` will care about.  The `Decoder` will not know of any successive bytes added after what has been described as it only sees what was described at the beginning.  Therefore, that error message `panic: extra data in buffer` is accurate.

In your Playground example, you are encoding twice to the same encoder instance and then closing the file.  Since you are passing exactly two records in, and encoding two records, that *may work* as the single instance of the encoder may see the two `Encode` calls as a single encoded stream.  Then when you close the file io's stream, the `gob` is now complete - and the stream is treated as a single record (even though you sent in two types).

And the same in the decoding function, you are reading X number of times from the same stream.  But, you are writing a single record when closing the file - that actually has two types in that one single record.  Hence why it works when reading 2, and EXACTLY 2.  But fails if reading more than 2.

A solution, if you want to store this in a single file, is that you will need to create your own index of each complete "write" or encoder instance/session.  Some form your own Block method that allows you to wrap or define each entry written to disk with a "begin" and "end" marker.  That way, when reading back the file, you know exactly what buffer to allocate because of the begin/end markers.  Once you have a single record in a buffer, then you use gob's `Decoder` to decode it.  And close the file after each write.

The pattern I use for such markers is something like:

```
uint64:uint64
uint64:uint64
...
```

The first being the beginning byte number, and the second entry separated by a colon being its length.  I usually store this in another file though, called appropriately `indexes`.  That way it can be quickly read into memory, and then I can stream the large file knowing exactly where each start and end address is in the byte stream.

Another option is just to store each `gob` in its own file, using the file system directory structure to organize as you see fit (or one could even use the directories to define types, for example).  Then the existence of each file is a single record.  This is how I use my rendered json from Event Sourcing techniques, storing millions of files organized in directories.

In summary, it would seem to me that a `gob` of data is a complete set of data from beginning to end - a single "record" have you.  If you want to store multiple encodings/multiple gobs, then to will need to create your own index to track the start and size/end of each `gob` bytes as you store them.  Then, you will want to `Decode` each entry separately.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. Another option should be to not close the encoder between successive writes. This should work until the app is shut down.

Comment: Yes, not closing would work.  Gob is special in that for every new type it encounters it writes a description record to define the fields & types.  By creating new encoders, it loses track of what types have been defined, so it starts defining them again on the second write.  Which, I assume, confuses the decoder.

Comment: It's almost like they are missing a `Close` mthod to indicate it is done.

Comment: One could argue that the Close is implicit: When there is no reference to the encoder anymore.