# Retrieval after serialization to disk using gob

Tags: go, serialization, gob

I have been learning about databases and wanted to implement one as well for learning purposes and not for production. I have a defined schema:

```
type Row struct {
    ID       int32
    Username string
    Email    string
}
```

Now, currently, i am able to encode structs of this type to a file in an append only manner.

```
//Just to show i use a file for the encoding, it has missing details.

func NewEncoder(db *DB) *gob.Encoder{
    return gob.NewEncoder(db.File)
}

func SerializeRow(r Row, encoder *gob.Encoder, db *DB) {
    err := encoder.Encode(r)
    if err != nil {
        log.Println("encode error:", err)
    }
}
```

Now, it's relatively easy to mimick a "select" statement by simply decoding the entire file using `gob.decode`

```
func DeserializeRow(decoder *gob.Decoder, db *DB){
    var rows Row
    db.File.Seek(0, 0)
    err := decoder.Decode(&rows)
    for err == nil {
        if err != nil {
            log.Println("decode error:", err)
        }
        fmt.Printf("%d %s %s\n", rows.ID, rows.Username, rows.Email)
        err = decoder.Decode(&rows)
    }
}
```

My current issue is, I want to be able to retrieve specific rows based on ID. I know `sqlite` uses 4kb paging, in the sense that serialized rows occupy a "page" ie. 4KB till a page can't hold them anymore, then another is created. How do I mimick such a behaviour using `gob` in the most simplistic and idiomatic way?

Seen: [I have seen this](https://%20https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30927993/append-to-golang-gob-in-a-file-on-disk) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37618399/efficient-go-serialization-of-struct-to-disk)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A Gob stream may contain type definitions and decoding instructions, so you can't seek a Gob stream. You can only read it from the beginning up to the point you find what you need.

A Gob stream is completely unsuitable for a database storage format in which you need to skip elements.

You could create a new encoder and serialize each records separately, in which case you could skip elements (by maintaining a file index storing which record starts at which position), but it would be terribly inefficient and redundant (as described in the [linked answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37620399/1705598), the speed and storage cost amortizes as you write more values of the same type, and always creating new encoders loses this gain).

A much better approach would be to not use `encoding/gob` for this, but rather define your own format. To efficiently support searches (`select`), you have to build some kind of index on the searchable columns / fields, else you still need to perform a full table scan.

Comment: Thanks for this. Are there any well known formats used for databases I could research into?

Comment: @KwakuBiney There are countless formats, use google to look into some of them.